# Skipping kubernetes service creation if it already exists with github actions

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, github-actions, amazon-eks

I set the following github action job to automatically deploy a "nginx" app on EKS and create a "nginx-service" service on push.

I'm trying to configure a skip in the service creation step when the service already exists.

My job:

```
name: CD_EKS

on:
  - push

jobs:
  eks_nginx_deployment_service:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Configure AWS Credentials
        uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
        with:
          aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
          aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
          aws-region: eu-central-1

      - name: Trigger deploy
        uses: Consensys/kubernetes-action@master
        env:
          KUBE_CONFIG_DATA: ${{ secrets.KUBE_CONFIG_DATA }}
        with:
          args: apply -f nginx_deployment.yaml

      - name: Get Service List
        id: get_service_list
        uses: Consensys/kubernetes-action@master
        env:
          KUBE_CONFIG_DATA: ${{ secrets.KUBE_CONFIG_DATA }}
        with:
          args: get services/nginx-service -o name

      - name: Create ELB service
        if: <service doesn't exist> # <- that's my point
        uses: Consensys/kubernetes-action@master
        env:
          KUBE_CONFIG_DATA: ${{ secrets.KUBE_CONFIG_DATA }}
        with:
          args: create -f nginx_loadbalancer.yaml
```

I tried to refer to the previous step (get_Service_list) output, unsuccessfully.

Thank you

Comment: Welcome! One item that helps drive higher quality answers (and questions) is to include what you've tried thus far, and what you've had an issue with. For example, are you having issues formatting conditionals, accessing the output of a previous step, or something else entirely? What is the actual code that you've tried, and what was the result?

Comment: If you change `kubectl create` to `kubectl apply`, it will work even if the Service already exists (it may change its configuration parameters).  Would it work to `apply` unconditionally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to skip a step based off of the output of a previous step, try out the following:

### Step 1 - Determine the name of the output you want to use

If you want to access the output of the `ConsenSys/kubernetes-action`, we first need to determine what the output's name is. Thankfully, ConsenSys documents this output via the YAML definition of the Action:

*[./.action.yml](https://github.com/ConsenSys/kubernetes-action/blob/master/action.yml#L11)*

```yaml
outputs:
  result:
    description: "Output of the kubectl command run"
```

To access the output of a step, GitHub Actions support the following expression: `${{ steps.STEP_ID.outputs.OUTPUT_NAME }}`

Since we know the ID of the step you want to use, and ConsenSys documents this Action's output, we then know the final expression is as follows: `${{ steps.get_service_list.outputs.result }}`

### Step 2 - Determine appropriate 'if' statement

From Step 1, we were able to determine that the output of `get_service_list` is the output of the kubectl command. This means that one will have to have a little knowledge about kubectl (experimenting locally can help with this). Since you are passing `get services/nginx-service -o name`, I am assuming that you are checking for the existence of an item named `services/nginx-service`. If it exists, `kubectl get services/nginx-service -o name` will output `services/nginx-service`. If it doesn't exist, kubectl will return an error. In other words, we can say that *if the output does **not equal** "services/nginx-service", run the step named "Create ELB service"*.

### Step 3 - Putting it all together

The above two steps gave us:

- The proper name of the `get_service_list` step's output
- The conditional we want to use for the step named "Create ELB service"

Putting those pieces of information together, the "Create ELB service" step could take on the following form:

```yaml
- name: Create ELB service
  if: steps.get_service_list.outputs.result != 'services/nginx-service'
  uses: Consensys/kubernetes-action@master
  env:
    KUBE_CONFIG_DATA: ${{ secrets.KUBE_CONFIG_DATA }}
  with:
    args: create -f nginx_loadbalancer.yaml
```

**note** GitHub Actions automatically assumes that the value of a conditional `if` keyword is an expression, so you do not have to surround the expression in `${{ }}`.

### Helpful Links/Notes

- [Supported Operators in GitHub Action Expressions](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/context-and-expression-syntax-for-github-actions#operators)
- [About contexts and expressions](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/context-and-expression-syntax-for-github-actions#about-contexts-and-expressions)

Comment: Thank you! Updated as follows:  
          ```- name: Get services list  
                with:  args: get services    
                  args: get services  
             - name: Create ELB service  
               if: contains(steps.get_services_list.outputs.result, 'nginx-service') == false  ...```